# Put followings when user is logged in

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud

I use soundcloud sdk. I want when user login to my site via soundcloud authentication that this user make a follow my soundcloud profile.

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'f5afdac70e530f7ba9a1b56e880b35a8',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost/SC/login.html'
});

// initiate auth popup
SC.connect().then(function() {
  return SC.get('/me');
}).then(function(me) {
    SC.put('/me/followings/190497691');
    alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
});
</script>
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
    <b style="text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

When user access my index.html, popup with sc login is showed, but after this nothing is happend.

I looked console log, and see this:
[Developer tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7agwg.jpg)

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advanced.